# I need help with blender lighting (uses sun posiiton addon)

Tags: add-on, lighting

[image]

here is the file to the scene
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sZFGuIMFfj594njDt9YmzaGgXk-O08Jm/view?usp=sharing
I honestly do not know what I am doing wrong, I've tried looking at the sun but it seems to be working okay, and the glitches only happen every few frames.

Comment: Hello and welcome. When posting here please avoid text inside images, always prefer typing it directly in the body of the post instead. Image content can't be indexed and thus can't be searched for or readily found in the future. It can't also be easily edited in case of errors or typos, nor updated when it gets outdated in case of future changes.

Comment: Also Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Which frames are glitched? Frame 9 rendered with Blender 3.5 beta on CPU looks normal (dark) to me.